# Menu with Bootstrap and jquery using css transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a simple menu with Bootstrap as following:
**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-inline b-square pull-right">
           <li id="one" data-name="one"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li id="two" data-name="two"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li id="three" data-name="three"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li id="four" data-name="four"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li id="five" data-name="five"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li id="six" data-name="six"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
b-square > li {
width : 24px;
height : 24px;
-webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: width 2s;
}



.b-square > li:hover {
width: 80px;
color: #fff;
text-align: right;


}

.b-square li#one {
background-color: #000;
padding: 2px 4px;
}

.b-square li#two {
background-color: #F7A600;
padding: 2px 4px;
}

.b-square li#three {
background-color: green;
padding: 2px 4px;
}

.b-square li#four {
background-color: #000;
padding: 2px 4px;
}


.b-square li#five{
background-color: #F7A600;
padding: 2px 4px;
}


.b-square li#six {
background-color: green;
padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.b-square > li').hover(function(){

        var name = $(this).data('name');    


       $(this).text(name);


        }, function(){
           $(this).text(''); 

        });   


        });
```

The menu contains six squares with different colours. The CSS hover effect increases the li width of 80px. The hover function in jQuery adds the link name of the selected **li**. 
The scripts work, but when I hover the **li** the selected square goes down instead of being alligned with the others ones.
Here is a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/jobgaraux/s3hdkgog/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with overflow: hidden:

```
.b-square > li {
   overflow: hidden; 
   width : 24px;
  height : 24px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Now it's working as expected,

Comment: Hi, I accepted your answer. Unfortunately this is my first post and I cannot vote yet.